# Error Python RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I got this error when re install in the python:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sendToBot' was never awaited
  sendToBot(message + " --",bot_id ,chat_id)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

my code :

```
async def sendToBot(message,bot_id,chat_id):
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_id)
    chat_id=chat_id 
    try:
        await bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as Err:
        print("Error, bot_id : " + bot_id + " channel_id : " + chat_id)
        print(Err)
```

I have no idea how to solve this, previous version work, but I cant recover my previous code.. any help?

Do I have to install previous telegram-bot?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you call an async function `sendToBot` without awaiting the coroutine.
Try to add `await` before your call;

```
await sendToBot(...)
```

Or, if you call it outside of an event loop, you could use asyncio.run:

```
import asyncio

asyncio.run(sendToBot(...))
```

You can learn more about coroutines and asyncio [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine).